# How do I change the sequence number in incremental format of files in Linux?

Tags: linux

Example of files :

```
abc25.txt #to abc1.txt
abc26.txt #to abc2.txt
.
.
.
```

Same format till 1000 sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Using [rename](/questions/tagged/rename):

```
$ rename -n 's/(\d+)/$1 - 24/e' files*
```

Remove `-n` switch when the output looks good to rename for real.

[man rename](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/rename/file-rename.1p.en.html)

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

The rename command that is part of the `util-linux` package, won't.

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result that contains `Perl script, ASCII text executable` and not containing `ELF`, then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo apt install rename
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /usr/bin/file-rename
```

---

For Mac users:

```
brew install rename
```

---

If you don't have this command with another distro, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL) (no deps...)

---

<sub><sup>This tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.</sup></sub>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109144/discussion-on-answer-by-gilles-quenot-how-do-i-change-the-sequence-number-in-inc).